# For a commutative ring R without identity, there exists a∈R such that Ra≠R

Tags: abstract-algebra, rngs

Is this statement true? Then how to prove it?

For a non trivial commutative ring $R$ without identity, there exists $a \in R\setminus \{0\}$ such that $Ra \not = R$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring without identity, and assume $Ra = R$ for some fixed $a$. Then in particular, there exists $e \in R$ with $ea=a$. For all $r \in R$, $e(ra) = (ea) r = ar = ra$, and since every element of $R$ can be written as $ra$ for some $r \in R$, this proves $e$ is an identity for $R$.

So this proves the stronger result that if $R$ is commutative and $Ra = R$ for *any* $a \in R$, then $R$ has an identity element.

Answer (score 2):

In the zero ring, $Ra=R$ for all $a$.

In a nonzero ring, $R\cdot 0\neq R$.

**Edit**: The question has since changed. The answer is still "not necessarily". In a field, $Ra=R$ for every nonzero $a$.

Comment: Thanks. Question needed to be edited to exclude trivial cases.

Comment: Field has an identity element.

Comment: @Guest_000 You said "not required to have an identity element", not "required not to have an identity element"...

Comment: My bad. English is not my native language.

Comment: @Guest_000 No worries, I understand.